# Weblogic 12.2.1 Infrastructure Jersey Jackson Configuration

Tags: jackson, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, weblogic12c

I'm using Jersey 2.22.1 on Weblogic 12.2.1. The managed server has a Jax-RS v1 service deployed. Jackson isn't working correctly and iThe non-json services are working as expected.

The error:

```
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Contract interface javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader can not be registered for component class com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider: Contract not assignable to component.
```

Pom.xml (there is a property setting jersey.version 2.22.1):

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
```

Weblogic.xml:

```
 <wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <!-- jsr311 -->
        <wls:package-name>javax.ws.rs.*</wls:package-name>
        <!-- javassist -->
        <wls:package-name>javassist.*</wls:package-name>
        <!-- aop repackaged -->
        <wls:package-name>org.aopalliance.*</wls:package-name>
        <!-- jersey 2 -->
        <wls:package-name>jersey.repackaged.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.glassfish.jersey.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.sun.research.ws.wadl.*</wls:package-name>
        <!-- hk2 -->
        <wls:package-name>org.glassfish.hk2.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.jvnet.hk2.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.jvnet.tiger_types.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    <wls:prefer-application-resources>
        <wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate</wls:resource-name>
        <!-- jersey -->
        <wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/org.glassfish.jersey.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>org.glassfish.jersey.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>jersey.repackaged.*</wls:resource-name>
        <!-- hk2 -->
        <wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/org.glassfish.hk2.*</wls:resource-name>


        <wls:resource-name>org.codehaus.jackson.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</wls:resource-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-resources>
</wls:container-descriptor>
```

Comment: This thread is interesting. It has a good relationship with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45652675/weblogic-12-2-1-2-how-to-tune-the-object-serializer-to-use-jackson-2-and-stran/45654884#45654884

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed my weblogic.xml to prefer package-name com.fasterxml.jackson.*, which was in the prefer-application-resources section above and it works correctly now. Here is a snippet of my weblogic.xml:

```
 <wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <!-- jsr311 -->
        <wls:package-name>javax.ws.rs.*</wls:package-name>
        <!-- javassist -->
        <wls:package-name>javassist.*</wls:package-name>
        <!-- aop repackaged -->
        <wls:package-name>org.aopalliance.*</wls:package-name>
        <!-- jersey 2 -->
        <wls:package-name>jersey.repackaged.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.glassfish.jersey.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.sun.research.ws.wadl.*</wls:package-name>
        <!-- hk2 -->
        <wls:package-name>org.glassfish.hk2.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.jvnet.hk2.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.jvnet.tiger_types.*</wls:package-name>
        <!--jackson-->
        <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    <wls:prefer-application-resources>
        <wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate</wls:resource-name>
        <!-- jersey -->
        <wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/org.glassfish.jersey.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>org.glassfish.jersey.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>jersey.repackaged.*</wls:resource-name>
        <!-- hk2 -->
        <wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/org.glassfish.hk2.*</wls:resource-name>


    </wls:prefer-application-resources>
</wls:container-descriptor>
```